# Replacing image in cell with Text "1"

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel that has 1 column with picture in each cell, that picture determines something but i would like to change it to 1 instead. There is only 1 picture, and to my exact, the column is J;Name =PO history/release documentation . Can someone help me to do it with VBA Thank you!

```
Public Sub Replace_Picture()
Const Replace_Text = &#34;OK&#34;
Dim shp as Shape

For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
If shp.TopLeftCell.Address = shp.BottomRightCell.Address Then
shp.TopLeftCell.Value = Replace_Text
shp.Delete
End If
Next

Set shp = Nothing
End Sub
```

I tried the above code but its not working and `const replace_text` is in red.
I just want to change those cells with the picture to "1", while those blanks will be leave it to be.

Comment: I am sorry I cannot understand what you want to do + you need to show us what you tried (your code) before we can help you improve it.

Comment: You might benefit from reading 
[Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/3219613)

Comment: ok i changed my question

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to delete the PO history shapes from SAP.
you may have a try by below VBA code.
Another way is you may 'Copy+Paste' data from SAP directly instead of 'Export to Excel'

```
Sub Replace_Shapes()
Dim Shp As Shape
Dim Shp_Address
For Each Shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
  If Shp.Type = msoPicture Then
     'Identify the address of Shape by TopLeft
     Shp_Address = Shp.TopLeftCell.Address
     Range(Shp_Address) = 1
     Shp.Delete    
  End If Next
End Sub
```